# Define repository for apache archiva with svn or any configuration file

Tags: apache, jenkins, repository, archiva

Is it possible to define apache archiva repository in configuration file and save it in SVN.
So that the repository does not need to be re-applied by hand in the next installation of Apache Archiva?

Answer (score 1):

Sure all is in one file.
Search the file $ARCHIVA_BASE/conf/archiva.xml and backup it.